# Простой сервер python под Винду

Tags: python, сервер

Доброго времени суток.
Не подскажете какой-нибудь простой python веб-сервер под Винду для тестирования скриптов на локалхосте? Очень желательно, чтобы старт/стоп были как в Денвере - два ярлычка: start и stop.  
Заранее спасибо.

П.С: Так как я пока мало в этом понимаю, если не пойму, как пользоваться сервером, буду задавать нубские вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Очень желательно, чтобы старт/стоп были как в Денвере - два ярлычка: start и stop.

http://www.denwer.ru/packages/python.html

UPD. Для других версий питона, полагаю, не будет никаких проблем подменить бинарники на другую версию [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython).

UPD 2. Да, еще советую попробовать [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Как все просто оказалось. =)

Answer (score 2):

В 90% случаев не нужен отдельный веб-сервер для *python*.
Если разработка под *Django*, *Flask* и другие фреймворки, то там есть встроенный веб-сервер для разработки, запускается одной командой в консоли и его не требуется выключать. 
Более того, там (в консоли) сразу можно увидеть логи, которые полезны для отладки.

Answer (score 1):

[cherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/)  - легкий питоносервер. Написан на питоне контрибутором языка специально "в духе" Python.

Answer (score 0):

Прикрутить Python к родному веб-серверу IIS и юзать через ASP-страницы